# Randomize values without exceeding a value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have some time thinking the following, I want to make a button to randomize whole values of some skills. The question is that I have 10 points to distribute between 4 skills, the idea is to have selected randoms numbers without exceeding 10 points.

I had thought in this

```
public int startPts = 10, usedPts = 0;
public int skill1 = 0, skill2 = 0, skill3 = 0, skill4 = 0;

public void ButtonRandom(){
   startPts = 10;
   usedPts = 0;

   skill1 = Random.Range( 1, 10 );
   usedPts += skill1;

   skill2 = Random.Range( 1, usedPts );
   usedPts += skill2;

   skill3 = Random.Range( 1, usedPts );
   usedPts += skill3;

   skill4 = startPts - usedPts;
   usedPts += skill4;

   startPts = startPts - usedPts;

 }
```

I also try with several conditionals and repetitive methods, but I do not get the desired result. Since sometimes it surpasses the 10 points, leaves points without using or only changes the first 2 values when I put the conditions.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Your last assignment needs to assign remaining points, not try to guess a random.  "skill4 = startPts - usedPts"

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually want to use `Random.Range( 1, startPts - usedPts );`? Right now your number generation doesn't at all take into account how many points are left available.

Comment: @Aaron Yes you're right I'll edit that part right now, thanks.

Comment: If the random distributes the 10 points in the first skills, what happens with the others? Do they get zero point?

Comment: Look at @Serlite 's comment too.  It looks like solid logic.  I focused in on the reason you were getting more/less than 10, not that you were maxing your random on used points.  If usedpoints is 6, you would really want the max random value to be 4 (remaining), not 6.  So you would want "startpts - usedpts" for your random value as well.

Comment: Guys thanks for your prompt reply, @Serlite You're right, although I've tried that before. I'll try again as you say.

Comment: I don't think your current approach is correct, you essentially have a 1 in 10 chance of assigning 10 points to your first skill. You have an almost zero chance of assigning 10 points to your last skill. I would assign a random number one to ten to all skills, then based on their percentage of the total you can apply an appropriate number.

Comment: @dcg the minimum for each skill must be 1.

Comment: Derrick Moeller is correct; this algorithm does not produce a uniform distribution of skills.  Is there a particular distribution you would like? Should, for instance, every possible combination of four items that adds up to ten be represented?

Comment: If that's what I've been thinking, but I should also have the possibility that the value is the maximum. There are always those possibilities, although the maximum should be 7 now that they say it.

Comment: The algorithm you want is: give each skill one point to start with. Then six times, choose a random skill and increment it by one. This guarantees (1) that the total will add to ten, (2) that each skill is at least one, and (3) that there is no particular skill that is favoured. It does not, however, guarantee that all possible distributions of ten points split four ways such that each skill has at least one point, are equally likely.

Comment: Exactly, I would like you to help me in making a distribution than the sum of the parts of 10, but 100% random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
int[] skills = new int[4];

int pointsToDistribute = 10;

var rnd = new Random ();

for (int i = 0; i < pointsToDistribute; i++)
{
    int whichSkill = rnd.Next (0, 4);

    skills[whichSkill]++;
}
```

Test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/891OlN

Comment: I think that every skill should start with a value of one, then the loop will go only to `pointsToDistribute - skills.Length`. It's a requirement of the question.

Comment: @dcg: I gave him just an idea, he can adapt it easily to his requirements. But you are right of course.

Comment: Hey @apocalypse I wanted to use the .Next () method but in Unity it seems that it can not be used or I think so. But this is the desired result, thank you man, now I would not know how to implant it with Unity.

Answer (score 8):

If what you want is for *every possible distribution to be equally likely*, then none of the solutions presented so far work.  The solutions presented so far pick `3, 3, 2, 2` much more often than `7, 1, 1, 1`. Do you see why?

If your desired distribution is uniform over possibilities, this algorithm gives you that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    // Partition n into m summands
    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Partitions(int n, int m)
    {
      // There is no partition of n into zero summands for any value of n other than zero.
      // Otherwise, give the partitions that begin with 0, 1, 2, ... n.
      if (m == 0) 
      {
        if (n == 0)
          yield return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
      }
      else 
      {
        for (int nn = 0; nn <= n; ++nn)
            foreach(var p in Partitions(n - nn, m - 1))
                yield return (new[] { nn }).Concat(p);
      }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Divide up six points into four buckets:
        var partitions = Partitions(6, 4).ToArray();
        // Now choose a random member of partitions, and 
        // add one to each element of that sequence. Now
        // you have ten points total, and every possibility is 
        // equally likely.

        // Let's visualize the partitions:
        foreach(var p in partitions)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", p));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *Unity* APIs this would look like this, building on @apocalypse s solution

```
    int[] skills = new int[4];
    int pointsToDistribute = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsToDistribute; i++) {
        int whichSkill = Random.Range (0, 4);
        skills [whichSkill]++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.
Each line has an explanation, but in short, this uses an array to store the randomly generated numbers.

```
public void RandomButton()
{
    int toDistribute = 10; // 10 points to distribute

    int[] skills = new int[4]; // Array that contains 4 skills

    Random random = new Random(); // New instance of Random

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // For loop that loops four times 
    {
        if (toDistribute > 0) // Do this IF there are points to distribute
        {
            int points = random.Next(0, toDistribute + 1); // Assign points a value between 0 and the remaining amount of points
            // Random.Next(lowerBoundary,upperBoundary-1) e.g. Random.Next(0,100) gives values from 0 to 99
            skills[i] = points; // The current skill is given the value of points
            toDistribute -= points; // Total number of points remaining is reduced by the number of points assigned this iteration
        } else break; // If there are no points, end the loop
    }
}
```

If you don't understand how Random.Next works, read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

***EDIT / UNITY UPDATE:***

Research has led me to believe that Random.Next() isn't readily available in Unity, and instead uses Random.Range. In this case, use the following:

```
int point = Random.Range(0,toDistribute);
```

Also, as far as I am understanding, you do not need to create a new instance of Random, meaning that

```
Random random = new Random();
```

can be removed

Answer (score 0):

Guys @apocalypse hit the target, I was studying every one of their algorithms and solutions, thank you all really. This is the result of my code, in case someone has the same doubt.

```
public int startPts = 10, usedPts = 0;
public int skill1 = 0, skill2 = 0, skill3 = 0, skill4 = 0;

public void ButtonRandom(){
   startPts = 10;
   usedPts = 0;

   int[] skills = new int[4];

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        skills[i] = 1;
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < (startPts - skills.Length); i++) {
        int tempRandom = Random.Range (0, 4);
        skills [tempRandom]++;
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        usedPts += skills[i];
    }

   startPts = startPts - usedPts;

   skill1 = skills[0];

   skill2 = skills[1];

   skill3 = skills[2];

   skill4 = skills[3];

}
```